# Why are rdfs and owl not working in this query?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, rdfs

This SPARQL query should print a list that has a first column stating the name of the disease the patient has, a second column stating the other factor for the death of the patient and finally a third column with the title of the paper that the information is on.

```
PREFIX snomed: <http://www.ihtsdo.org/SCT_>
PREFIX sct: <http://wasp.cs.vu.nl/sct/sct#>
PREFIX drugbank: <https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/>
PREFIX ztonekg:<http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#>
PREFIX pubmed:<http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    select distinct ?disease ?suicide ?title
    where {
    ?diseaseid rdfs:subClassOf snomed:73595000.
    ?t1s1 ztonekg:SenseURL ?diseaseid.
    ?diseaseid sct:hasEnglishLabel ?disease.
    ?t1 ztonekg:hasSense ?t1s1.
    ?s7 ztonekg:hasSenses ?t1.    
    ?s ztonekg:hasTerm ?s7.      
    ?s1 ztonekg:hasAnnotation ?s.
    ?s1 ztonekg:hasSource "Title".
    ?pubmed ztonekg:hasAnnotations ?s1.
    ?pubmed ztonekg:hasAnnotations ?s1b.
    ?s1b ztonekg:hasSource "Title".
    ?s1b ztonekg:hasAnnotation ?sb.
    ?sb ztonekg:hasTerm ?s7b.
    ?s7b ztonekg:hasSenses ?t1b.
    ?t1b ztonekg:hasSense ?t1s1b.
    ?t1s1b ztonekg:SenseURL ?suicideid.
    ?suicideid rdfs:subClassOf snomed:262188008. #suice:44301001
    ?suicideid sct:hasEnglishLabel ?suicide.
    ?s1b ztonekg:hasText ?title.   
    }
```

The only solution that I have for now is to bypass the problem which is caused by

- ?diseaseid rdfs:subClassOf snomed:73595000.
- ?suicideid rdfs:subClassOf snomed:262188008.

by doing it like this

*same prefixes as before*

```
   select ?t1s1 ?t1s1b ?title
    where { 
    ?t1s1 ztonekg:SenseURL snomed:248062006. #40683002.#248062006.#self-harm
    ?t1 ztonekg:hasSense ?t1s1.
    ?s7 ztonekg:hasSenses ?t1.    
    ?s ztonekg:hasTerm ?s7.
    ?s1 ztonekg:hasAnnotation ?s.
    ?s1 ztonekg:hasSource "Title".
    ?pubmed ztonekg:hasAnnotations ?s1.
    ?pubmed ztonekg:hasAnnotations ?s1b.
    ?s1b ztonekg:hasSource "Title".
    ?s1b ztonekg:hasAnnotation ?sb.
    ?sb ztonekg:hasTerm ?s7b.
    ?s7b ztonekg:hasSenses ?t1b.
    ?t1b ztonekg:hasSense ?t1s1b.
    ?t1s1b ztonekg:SenseURL snomed:133937008.#adolescent
    ?s1b ztonekg:hasText ?title.
    }
```

But I would like the first way to work since in further steps of this project I will need to use that subject

Comment: the question is, does your data  contain an RDF triple `snomed:248062006 
  rdfs:subClassOf   snomed:73595000 .` which I doubt if the result is empty. So did you load the SNOMED taxonomy you're querying?

Comment: my data doesnt have that RDF triple, but why would it? Since the two snomed should not be linked through rdfs:subClassOf in this query. I am maybe wrong, but what would be a solution to creating a subclass for both snomed to be able to print it in the table?